# Ajax loader script for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have list element like this

```
<ol class="listItem">
    <li id="#item-1" class="NewsFeedItem">
        <a href="someurl.com" class="threadLink">Example Url</a>
        <div class="attachedImage"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="#item-2" class="NewsFeedItem">
        <a href="someurl2.com" class="threadLink">Example Url 2</a>
        <div class="attachedImage"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="#item-3" class="NewsFeedItem">
        <a href="someurl3.com" class="threadLink">Example Url 3</a>
        <div class="attachedImage"></div>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

I want to use just **one script** to load content for each `li`. I wrote some code here but it isn't working

```
$('.NewsFeedItem').each(function() {
var id = $(this).get(0).id;

$('#' + id + '.attachedImage').load( $('#' + id + '.threadLink').attr('href') + ' .firstPost .messageText img' );

});
```

Where was I wrong?

Comment: `#` is wrong since you're getting `id` including `#` remove `#` from your selector and check!

Comment: @31piy it didn't load content

Comment: @DhavalMarthak like this?
`$(id + '.attachedImage').load( $(id + '.threadLink').attr('href') + ' .firstPost .messageText img' );`
It's still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, except at two points. To select the descendants, you need to separate the selectors by a space, which you are lacking in this line:

```
$('#' + id + ' .attachedImage').load( $('#' + id + ' .threadLink').attr('href') ...
```

A selector like `#id.attachedImage` will look for an element with ID as `id`, having a class `attachedImage` assigned to it.

If you want to select an element, having a class `attachedImage` assigned to it, and which is a descendant of an element of ID `id`, you need to write the selector as `#id .attachedImage`.

---

**Edit 1:**

Since the value in id already has a `#`, you need to remove the `#` from your selectors as well:

```
$( id + ' .attachedImage').load( $( id + ' .threadLink').attr('href') ...
```

Comment: BTW, since I use just one script instead of each script for each element, I got so many notices like this: https://i.imgur.com/4hjFhEh.png
How to fix this ?

Comment: @MCN -- Loading the external fonts are causing these warnings. You may want to minimize the number of web fonts you're loading on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove '#'

```
$( id + '.attachedImage').load( $( id + '.threadLink').attr('href') + '.firstPost .messageText img' );
```